# MySQL does joining on MUL keys impact performance?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I'm using a MySQL query that does three table joins on four tables. Two of these joins are on a pair of MUL keys. The third join is on a pair of primary keys. The query takes a full minute to grab 100 rows.

I believe that both pairs of MUL keys are unique; and so I'm wondering, if these keys were to be indexed as unique, or made into foreign keys, would I notice a significant performance enhancement?

Are the joins on MUL keys likely the culprit here?

**Edit**

Okay, here's the schema. I substituted letters for the actual table/column names.

```
mysql> describe table A;
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| pkey              | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| mkey              | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| a                 | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| b                 | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
```

```
mysql> describe table B;
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| pkey              | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| mkey1             | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| mkey2             | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| a                 | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| b                 | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| c                 | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
```

```
mysql> describe table C;
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| pkey          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| mkey          | varchar(128)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
```

```
mysql> describe table D;
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| pkey          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| mkey          | varchar(128)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
```

Query:

```
select
A.a, A.b, B.c, A.mkey, C.pkey, D.mkey
from
A, B, C, D
where
A.pkey=C.pkey and
A.mkey=B.mkey1 and
B.mkey2=D.pkey and
B.a <= A.a and
B.b >= A.b
D.mkey in ('str1', 'str2', ...);
```

Returns 77 rows.

Comment: both `MUL`, `FOREIGN` and `UNIQUE` keys are automatically indexed. So performace should be the same. Foreign keys preserves referential integrity around records on tables.

Comment: Automatically indexed? I thought you had to manually index a MySQL table.

Comment: no, once you define `key` on the column(s), index are automatically created on them.

Comment: Also, by indexing, does it mean that MUL keys which are unique are treated as unique? (That is, when it finds a row in table A to join with table B it will join it, and stop looking for more rows.)

Comment: *does it mean that MUL keys which are unique are treated as unique?* -- yes.

Comment: Check that you actually are using your multi-column indexes in the query : [`any leftmost prefix of the index can be used by the optimizer to find rows`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

Comment: from MySQL Doc, `Most MySQL indexes (PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE, INDEX, and FULLTEXT) are stored in B-trees.`

Comment: @bmewsing: I wasn't aware you had to embed the index prefixes (?) in the query. Do I actually have to modify the query to make use of indexing?

Comment: @ktm5124 I mean that if you have an index (col1, col2, col3) but you are joining just on (col1, col3) then the index won't be used. The left most attributes can only be used ie (col1), (col1, col2), (col1, col2,col3)

Comment: @bmewsing Excellent point.

Comment: I see. We haven't defined any indexes on the tables ourselves. The ones that exist were automatically generated from the keys (see JW's comment). So, I'm not sure if that point would apply.

Comment: @ktm5124 post your schema and EXPLAIN output and someone will be able to tell you if you have a problem.

Comment: Are the tables MyISAM or InnoDB? Can you add the EXPLAIN plan?

Answer (score 0):

Use explicit joins

```
select
A.a, A.b, B.c, A.mkey, C.pkey, D.mkey
from
A INNER JOIN C ON (A.pkey = C.pkey)
INNER JOIN B ON (A.mkey = B.mkey1)
INNER JOIN D ON (B.mkey2 = D.pkey)
where
B.a <= A.a and
B.b >= A.b
D.mkey in ('str1', 'str2', ...);
```

Comment: and why do you bump up all those necroquestions? =)